# Please Add - list of PHP CMS and the Template Engines they use

Tags: php, templates, content-management-system, template-engine

For research purposes, I'd like to compile a list of PHP CMSs and the template engine they use. Please add what you use or know and I will add it here

- Drupal => [PHPTemplate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPTemplate) (custom theming engine for drupal since 2005) and [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a list of CMS for PHP (excluding proprietary, which are also listed above): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems#PHP_2

As you can see there are too many for us to list all the template engines for you.